# Reading Rows into Variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following T-SQL in MSSQL,

```
Declare @S table(StartAc bigint)
Declare @E table(EndAc bigint)
Declare @B table(BNum varchar(20))

Select StartAc=[Start] from [dbo].[CFC] 
Select EndAc=[EndCode] from [dbo].[CFC]
Select ENum=[ENum] from [dbo].[CFC]

;with CFile as (
    Select StartAc as AcNum 
    from @S 
    union all 
    Select AcNum+1 
    from CFile 
    where AcNum+1 <=EndAc
)

Insert into dbo.list 
Select ENum,* 
from CFile Option(Maxrecursion 32676)
```

Actually I have a table with EmployeeID,StartingNumber and EndingNumber (lets say Ranges),I need to generate all Numbers between those Starting and EndingNumbers for all Employees.I created using Single Employee but not working for all Employees.

Comment: No, you don't need a loop, but you might need a table variable instead of a scalar variable.

Comment: What do you want to do with that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actual desire is much different than your iginal question.

What you need to do is this:

```
select 'asdf' as empid, 1 as StartAc, 100 as EndAc into #emptbl;

insert #emptbl Values ('blah', 203, 400)

;with nums(Number, EmpID, StartAc, EndAc) as
(SELECT
        StartAc as Number,
        empid,
        StartAc,
        EndAc
    FROM #emptbl
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Number + 1, empid, StartAc, EndAc
    FROM Nums 
    WHERE Number < EndAc
)
SELECT EmpID, Number from Nums ORDER BY EmpID Option(Maxrecursion 32676);

drop table #emptbl
```

---

(To original question)

If you know the data set will be small and only need to be held in memory for a little bit, won't require any additional indexes/column modifications, use a table variable.

```
DECLARE @data TABLE(EmpID bigint)

INSERT INTO @data(EmpID)
SELECT [EID] FROM [dbo].[EmplyeeFC]
```

Otherwise, use a temp table.

```
SELECT [eid] INTO #data FROM [dbo].[EmplyeeFC]
ALTER #data add AnotherCol int null;
ALTER #data ADD CONSTRAINT ...
...  other code ...
DROP TABLE #data
```

It would be possible to use a cursor to loop through your data, but this is defeating the purpose of using SQL in the first place - set based operations (using tables) will be far more performant and maintainable.

Comment: Declare @S table(StartAc bigint)
Declare @E table(EndAc bigint)
Declare @B table(BNum varchar(20))
Select StartAc=[Start] from [dbo].[CFC] 
Select EndAc=[EndCode] from [dbo].[CFC]
Select ENum=[ENum] from [dbo].[CFC]
;
with CFile as (Select StartAc as AcNum from @S union all Select AcNum+1 from CFile where AcNum+1 <=EndAc)
Insert into dbo.list 
Select ENum,* from CFile Option(Maxrecursion 32676)

Comment: It's really ahrd to read your code like that..  Try editing your question with the actual code and expected result.

Comment: Edited main Question,please check

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a *scalar* variable to store multiple values. You have to use a *table* variable instead:

```
DECLARE @data TABLE(EmpID bigint)

INSERT INTO @data(EmpID)
SELECT [EID] FROM [dbo].[EmplyeeFC]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use curor to loop for all row in query

```
DECLARE @EmpID Bigint
DECLARE CurEmplyeeFC  CURSOR FOR 
SELECT EID  
FROM EmplyeeFC  

OPEN CurEmplyeeFC
FETCH NEXT FROM CurEmplyeeFC INTO @EmpID 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- loop traitement here
    FETCH NEXT FROM CurEmplyeeFC INTO @EmpID
END

CLOSE CurEmplyeeFC
```

Comment: While this is technically possible, it should not be used.  It will perform horribly and is not necessary (Table Variables and/or temp tables can solve his problem)

Comment: @DanField Okay it comes a technical choice

Comment: Sure, and there can be cases where a cursor is justified so it doesn't hurt to know it.